# Does Linux 3.1 support Intel Optane?

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, sata, nvme

Does Arch Linux kernel 3.1 support Intel Optane? It boots in my system on SATA. Is there Intel Optane on SATA? Or does Linux 3.1 support any other Optane interface (like NVMe)? It is a digital music server with very low latency. The system is not on network, security is not a concern.

```
~ $ uname -a
Linux server1 3.10.14-rt9-1-rt #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Oct 9 ... 2013 x86_64
```

Comment: Kinda defeats the point of Arch Linux if you're on such an old kernel

Comment: @muru Why? The purpose is a low latency music server and it works. What would be the advantage of a newer kernel for the same purpose on the same hardware?

Comment: You're currently something like 40 releases behind, I'd imagine some improvements have been made to whatever subsystems you're using most. That's what Arch shines at - getting the latest and greatest without complicating things too much.

Comment: You are wondering if some ancient kernel version supports a recent piece of hardware. More recent kernels are most likely to support more recent hardware.

Comment: @Bananguin Consider you have a 5-y/o car in a perfect condition. You like it and it drives fine. Then you read of new tires with a great traction. So you ask if you can find them for the wheels on you car. Yet you hear in response, "More recent tires are most likely to fit more recent car models". Well, true, but... it doesn't answer your question, does it?

Comment: @muru It is helpful to know this fact about Arch. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: You realize that security vulnerabilities in kernels are a thing, right?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - Not for a standalone music server at home.

Comment: @Hiroyashu So it's never connected to the Internet, and neither are any of the computers or other devices that ever connect to it? Because otherwise, it's not standalone, and security vulnerabilities do matter.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes, just local music files with no Internet.

Comment: @Hiroyashu To publicly respond to your question, I have two types of messages available to me: comments and answers. Posting answers as comments defeats the purpose of either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Optane should just show up as a normal block device as far as Linux is concerned, so you can use it like any other disk* was noted at https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/a0ys0v/anything_useful_we_can_do_with_intel_optane_cache/

bcache also [can access Optane](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bcache).